# unacceptable character #x001b: special characters are not allowed

Tags: python-3.x, yaml

I'm trying to read a yaml file with a name given in argument.
For example

> python3 temp.py myfile.yaml

But I'm getting an error

> python3 temp2.py myfile
> unacceptable character #x001b: special characters are not allowed   in
> "myfile.yaml", position 0

Here is my .py file

```
import os, yaml
    import argparse
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='read requested yaml file')
    parser.add_argument('file', type=str, help='name of the file to read')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    
    with open(args.file, 'r') as stream:
        try:
            result=yaml.safe_load(stream)#<<<<I tried mutiples things, and I'm sure the error is here
            print(['spec']['links'])

        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
```

And finaly my myfile.yaml

```
---
kind: manifest
scope: xxx
metadata: {}
spec:
  links:
    - name: yy
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Your problem cannot be reproduced by the information currently in your question because we don't have access to `myfile.yaml`. Please also read the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953) and provide the _full stack trace_ of the error.

Comment: As requested, I have corriged my question